# Creating lists of indexes based on a data frames column's values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I would like to extract lists of indexes based on the value of column `ID`.

```
data={'ID':[1,1,2,3,6,4,2,6], 'Number': [10,20,5,6,100,90,40,5]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I know how to do that manually, one value/list at a time:

```
 idx_list=df.index[df.ID == 1].tolist()
```

but in my code, I usually don't know how many different values of ID I have, so the above approach would not be enough.
Ideally I would like to have multiple lists as output. for each value of ID, a list of indexes.

Comment: Do you atleast would know the different values of id contained in some list on which you can filter

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I just know that most likely it would be an integer number between [1,5].

Comment: I think you need [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop

```
idx_list = []
for ID in data["ID"]:
    idx_list.append(df.index[df.ID == ID].tolist())
```

This will give you the indices for each `ID`. Note that there will be duplicates. To avoid this, only add to `idx_list` if the value is already not present:

```
idx_list = []
for ID in data["ID"]:
    if df.index[df.ID == ID].tolist() not in idx_list: idx_list.append(df.index[df.ID == ID].tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the list of indexes for each value you want to filter for in aseparate container

```
i_list=[]
for x in df.ID:
    i_list.append(df.index[df['ID'] == x].tolist())
```

`i_list` contains the list of indexes as a `2D` list

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Himanshu Poddar, ideally I would like to have multiple lists as output. for each value of ID, a list of indexes.